# How can I set environment variable in DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: django

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

If I give above coding in terminal, it throws below error. I am using ubuntu. How can I set environment variable? I am using python 2.7.6 version.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Comment: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.settings`

Answer (score 0):

I once had to do this, in order to get database-related testing to work in a project I did:

```
import os
if not 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' in os.environ or os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] != '<myProject>.settings':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<myProject>.settings'

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: I tried with above samples.But it throws error.What should i need to put in that place of <myProject> whether my path or not.My path is like /home/django-rest-hooks/myproject .In that myproject folder i have given all the .py file.How can i run this package.I took this all coding from django website.

Comment: If your project is called fooBar, then you should enter 'fooBar.settings'. The project must contain a settings.py file, and an `__init__.py` file which should be empty.